# Escape Mechinze Error in Ruby Scraping

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am getting the following server response error while trying to scrape SERP results:

```
/Users/*********/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:323:in `fetch': 503 => Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable for http://******.*****.com/sorry/index?continue=http://www.********.com/search%3Fq%3D<term1>%2B<term2> -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
```

I am trying to figure out how to escape the error / exception, so that the program will continue to run instead of automatically exiting.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Point taken, read the suggested docs. Will aim to incorporate those principals into subsequent questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like anything in Ruby it probably boils down to `rescue` and recover:

```
loop do
  begin
    Mechanize.do_stuff!

    # Success!
    break

  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    # Server-side failure, so let's try again after a quick break
    sleep(10)
  end
end
```

Note the `sleep(10)` is there to avoid slamming the server furiously and making it malfunction even harder.

Comment: Why is the break statement required?

Comment: I'm presuming you don't want to fetch the same page over and over, forever.